# Find the date given the year, the month and the "nth" occurrance of day within the month C/C++

Tags: c++, c, datetime, timezone, dst

In order that a device (with limited memory) is able to manage its own timezone and daylight savings, I'm trying to calculate daylight savings triggers for 85 time zones based on a simplified description of each timezone. I have access to minimal C and C++ libraries within the device. The format of the timezone (inc. DST) description for each time zone is as follows:

- UTC - the base time and date from system clock
- GMTOffsetMinutes - offset from GMT with DST inactive
- DSTDeltaMinutes - modifier to above with DST active (as applicable to TZ)
- DSTStartMonth - month in which DST becomes active
- DSTStartNthOccurranceOfDay - the nth occurrence of the day name in month
- DSTDayOfWeek - Sun = 0 through to Sat = 6
- DSTStartHour - hour at which DST becomes active
- DSTStartMinute - minute at which DST becomes active
- and corresponding EndMonth, EndNth..., EndHour, EndMinute

I have found numerous examples going the other way, i.e. starting with the date, but they involve using the modulus, keeping the remainder and dropping the quotient hence I have been unable to transpose the formula to suit my needs.

I also tried to reuse the standard "Jan = 6, Feb = 2, Mar = 2, Apr = 5, May = 0, etc. modifier table and year modifiers from the "tell me what day the 25th of June, 2067 is?" party trick and developed the following algorithm.

```
Date = DayOfWeek + ((NthOccuranceOfDay - 1) x 7 ) - MonthCode - YearCode
```

This worked for the first 6 random test dates I selected but then I started to see dates for which it failed. Is it possible that the basic algorithm is sound but I'm missing a further modifier or maybe that I'm applying the modifiers incorrectly?

Is there another solution I could utilize?

Comment: For clarification, are you saying that your device can't divide? Or why is it impossible to use a solution which requires modulus?

Comment: @Bathsheba boost is not the answer for everything. Especially if `I have access to minimal C and C++ libraries within the device`.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek That close is uncalled-for in my opinion. It's a simple mathematical error which has an obvious solution; the question is clear.

Comment: That formula will be off by one week if MonthCode + YearCode is greater than or equal to DayOfWeek, because in that case you will be counting from a negative date. You need to check for that condition and add 7 if it is the case. (Question was closed before I manage to finish typing the answer.)

Comment: No rici, I'm saying that the solution that carries out the reverse operation, calculates the modulus for further use but discards the quotient from the same calculation, i.e. the quotient is unimportant when carrying out the reverse operation. In order to transpose, I would need to feed in both the modulus and quotient (along with the divisor) to arrive at the original dividend.

Comment: **There is no language C/C++!** Pick one language!

Comment: Thanks rici... I'll give that a whirl.

Comment: @MickM:  I voted to reopen.  In the meantime, this library might be helpful to you: http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_v2.html  With it you can write expressions such as `tue[3]/may/2015` which represents the 3rd Tuesday of May in 2015.  That can be converted to a serial count of days, or to a year/month/day format, all very easily, and very accurately.  It is based on the low-level date algorithms presented here: http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html  C++11 or C++14 is required for the date lib, but not for the algorithms.

Comment: Note that 1) DST changes often; 2) most countries switch on the *last* occurrence of a weekday, which is either the 4th or 5th; and 3) in Brazil, you need to know when it's *carnaval*.

Comment: Haha... Yeah, we are aware of carnaval and many other anomolies. I spent a number of weeks tying myself in knots over such things before opting for a simpler approach. Our table which describes the info listed above is produced (and updated) externally and I parse out the info for each build. Early on I looked at using the comprehensive Linux DST tables but just don't have the space.

Comment: Fwiw, here is a C++11/14 parser of the IANA timezone database: http://howardhinnant.github.io/tz.html

Comment: Thanks Howard... I'll be sure to take a look at your solutions.

Comment: This seems to work: 

date = DoW + (((WoM - (yearCode + monthCode <= DoW)) * 7) - monthCode - yearCode); 

For more situations but I need to test further and make further modifications for the "2 weeks out scenario".

Comment: Further modifier added: <br>

    date = DoW + (((WoM - y) * (yearCode + monthCode <= DoW)) - monthCode - yearCode) + ((yearCode + monthCode >= (DoW + 7) * 7);

Answer (score 1):

Using [this open source, cross platform date library](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html), one can write:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    year_month_day us_daylight_starts = sys_days(sun[2]/mar/2015);
    year_month_day us_daylight_ends   = sys_days(sun[1]/nov/2015);
    std::cout << us_daylight_starts << '\n';
    std::cout << us_daylight_ends << '\n';
}
```

which will output:

```
2015-03-08
2015-11-01
```

The formulas this library is based on are in the public domain and [documented here](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html).

The algorithms paper has very complete unit tests validating the date algorithms over a range of millions of years (a far larger range than is necessary).

Sometimes daylight savings rules are written in terms of the *last* weekday of a month.  That is just as easily handled:

```
year_month_day ymd = sys_days(sun[last]/nov/2015);
std::cout << ymd << '\n';  // 2015-11-29
```

Answer (score 0):

That formula will be off by one week (or even two weeks) if `MonthCode` + `YearCode` is greater than or equal to `DayOfWeek`, because in that case you will be counting `NthOccurenceOfDay` from a negative date.

As an alternative, with no tables, you can compute the day of week of the first of the month using, for example, [Zeller's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week#Zeller.E2.80.99s_algorithm):

```
int NthOccurrence(int year, int month, int n, int dayOfWeek) {
  // year is the current year (eg. 2015)
  // month is the target month (January == 1...December == 12)
  // Finds the date of the nth dayOfWeek (Sun == 0...Sat == 6)

  // Adjust month and year
  if (month < 3) { --year, month += 12; }
  // The gregorian calendar is a 400-year cycle
  year = year % 400;
  // There are no leap years in years 100, 200 and 300 of the cycle.
  int century = year / 100;
  int leaps = year / 4 - century;
  // A normal year is 52 weeks and 1 day, so the calendar advances one day.
  // In a leap year, it advances two days.
  int advances = year + leaps;
  // This is either magic or carefully contrived,
  // depending on how you look at it:
  int month_offset = (13 * (month + 1)) / 5;
  // From which, we can compute the day of week of the first of the month:
  int first = (month_offset + advances) % 7;
  // If the dayOfWeek we're looking for is at least the day we just
  // computed, we just add the difference. Otherwise, we need to add 7.
  // Then we just add the desired number of weeks.
  int offset = dayOfWeek - first;
  if (offset < 0) offset += 7;
  return 1 + offset + (n - 1) * 7;
}
```

Comment: Disclaimer:  This formula is valid for the proleptic Gregorian calendar back to `Wed 0000-03-01`, but no earlier.  That is an impressive range, but it should be noted.

Comment: @howard. Fair enough. As far as I remember, daylight savings time is a more recent invention than the Gregorian calendar -- or even time zones -- so in the context of the application, I don't think it is necessary to consider any proleptic year, and much less whether to follow Bede's null-free numerology. But consider the limitation noted.

Comment: I suspect it could be modified to handle negative years by changing `year = year % 400` to floored or Euclidian division: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation  But I have not tested that suspicion.  Agreed that such a change would be targeting a very small audience.  Fwiw, the earliest entry in the IANA timezone database is 1835-01-01. :-)

Comment: @howard: iirc, time zones were a response to the needs of the railway timetable; prior to the existence of a transportation medium with predictable duration, it was not really problematic for every village to idiosyncratically use its own town clock to define the local time. And yes, using a more sensible modulus function and astronomic year numbering would proleptically extend the algorithm to the beginning of `int`-representable time.